# jenkins download artifacts using REST api

Tags: java, rest, jenkins, continuous-integration

There is a maven project that has been configured to keep last 5 builds and discard old ones so when accessing the uri:

`http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/jobname/buildId/api/json`

artifacts are empty

`"artifacts":[]`

Is there any way to download the artifacts from the last successful build?

**Note:** 
The artifacts are present at this location: `http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/jobName/default/ws/`

Answer (score 1):

Recently needed to do this and thought I'd add my answer here.  There may be easier ways of doing this but I didn't see them documented anywhere.  Hopefully this can at least help get someone started.

I used the [jenkins-rest](https://github.com/cdancy/jenkins-rest) library mentioned in the jenkins-API docs:

```
//  Added to my build.gradle dependencies     
classpath "io.github.cdancy:jenkins-rest:1.0.2"
classpath "commons-io:commons-io:2.6"
```

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import com.cdancy.jenkins.rest.JenkinsClient
import com.cdancy.jenkins.rest.domain.job.JobInfo
import com.cdancy.jenkins.rest.domain.job.BuildInfo
import com.cdancy.jenkins.rest.features.JobsApi



//  The name of the job whose build artifacts we want
String jobName = "jobName"


//  Create connection to server
JenkinsClient client = JenkinsClient.builder().endPoint("https://your.jenkins.server:8443")
     .credentials("USERNAME:API_TOKEN")
     .build()


//  Create object to interact with jobs
JobsApi jobsApi = client.api().jobsApi()


//  Find the number of the lastSuccessfull build.
JobInfo info = jobsApi.jobInfo(null, jobName)
BuildInfo buildInfo = info.lastSuccessfulBuild()
int buildNumber = buildInfo.number


//  Downloads all artifacts from build as a .zip directory
File outputFile = new File(DOWNLOAD_PATH, "archive.zip")
outputFile.createNewFile()
try (InputStream inputStream = jobsApi.artifact(null, jobName, buildNumber, '*zip*/archive.zip')) {
     println("Downloading artifact")
     FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, outputFile)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this url
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/jobName/**lastSuccessfulBuild**/artifact/

Comment: Do you know the artifact names?

Comment: This would return the artifact content how would this download the artifact?